# How do I define an anonymous scalar ref in Perl?

Tags: perl, reference, scalar

How do I properly define an anonymous scalar ref in Perl?

`my $scalar_ref = ?;`

`my $array_ref = [];`

`my $hash_ref = {};`

Comment: You can intialize it to zero: perl -E '$a=\0; say $a; say $$a' so `$a` is now a scalar reference and the contents of the reference is the scalar 0.

Comment: See my updated rant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you just declare and don't initialize it.

```
my $foo; # will be undef.
```

You have to consider that empty hash refs and empty array refs point to a data structure that has a representation. Both of them, when dereferenced, give you an empty list.

[perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values) says (emphasis mine):

> There are actually two varieties of null strings (**sometimes referred to as "empty" strings**), a defined one and an **undefined one**. The defined version is just a string of length zero, such as "" . The undefined version is the value that indicates that there is no real value for something, such as when there was an error, or at end of file, or when you refer to an uninitialized variable or element of an array or hash. Although in early versions of Perl, an undefined scalar could become defined when first used in a place expecting a defined value, this no longer happens except for rare cases of autovivification as explained in perlref. You can use the defined() operator to determine whether a scalar value is defined (this has no meaning on arrays or hashes), and the undef() operator to produce an undefined value.

So an *empty scalar* (which it didn't actually say) would be `undef`. If you want it to be a reference, make it one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my $scalar_ref = \undef;
my $scalar = $$scalar_ref;

p $scalar_ref;
p $scalar;
```

This will output:

```
\ undef
undef
```

However, [as ikegami pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879261/how-do-i-define-an-anonymous-scalar-ref-in-perl/31879284?noredirect=1#comment51679363_31879284), it will be read-only because it's not a variable. [LeoNerd provides a better approach for this in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880478/1331451).

---

Anyway, my point is, an empty hash ref and an empty array ref when dereferenced both contain an empty list `()`. And that is not `undef` but *nothing*. But there is no *nothing* as a scalar value, because everything that is *not nothing* is a scalar value.

```
my $a = [];

say ref $r;     # ARRAY
say scalar @$r; # 0
say "'@$r'";    # ''
```

So there is no real way to initialize with *nothing*. You can only **not initialize**. But Moose will turn it to `undef` anyway.

What you could do is make it *maybe a scalar ref*.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

{
    package Foo;
    use Moose;

    has bar => ( 
      is => 'rw', 
      isa => 'Maybe[ScalarRef]', 
      predicate => 'has_bar' 
    );
}

my $foo = Foo->new;

p $foo->has_bar;
p $foo;

say $foo->bar;
```

**Output:**

```
""

Foo  {
    Parents       Moose::Object
    public methods (3) : bar, has_bar, meta
    private methods (0)
    internals: {}
}
Use of uninitialized value in say at scratch.pl line 268.
```

The `predicate` gives a value that is *not true* (the empty string `""`). `undef` is also not true. The people who made Moose decided to go with that, but it really doesn't matter.

Probably what you want is not have a default value, but just make it a `ScalarRef` an `required`.

---

Note that [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) doesn't say anything about initializing an empty scalar ref either.

Comment: That defines an empty scalar which I can create a reference to, but how can I define it anonymously?

Comment: Why do you need to? A scalar ref is a scalar.

Comment: I'm creating a `Moose` object that has an attribute of type `ScalarRef` and I want to define a default value for it.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 if you really want to do that, and require it to be defined, a sensible option would be `default => sub { \(my $var) }`. It's not anonymous in the strictest sense, but the name `$var` stops existing almost as soon as it's mentioned.

Comment: `default => do { \my $var }` is slightly cheaper than `default => sub { \my $var }`

Comment: @ikegami thank you for pointing that out. I ammended that part of my answer. Also I think the focus of my answer vs. LeoNerd's answer is really the part about Moose and not initializing at all.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a reference to some mutable storage, there's no particularly neat direct syntax for it. About the best you can manage is

```
my $var;
my $sref = \$var;
```

Or neater

```
my $sref = \my $var;
```

Or if you don't want the variable itself to be in scope any more, you can use a do block:

```
my $sref = do { \my $tmp };
```

At this point you can pass `$sref` around by value, and any mutations to the scalar it references will be seen by others.

This technique of course works just as well for array or hash references, just that there's neater syntax for doing that with `[]` and `{}`:

```
my $aref = do { \my @tmp };  ## same as  my $aref = [];

my $href = do { \my %tmp };  ## same as  my $href = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why you need to but I'd suggest:

```
my $ref = \undef;
print ref $ref;
```

Or perhaps:

```
my $ref = \0;
```

Answer (score 0):

@LeoNerd's answer is spot on.
Another option is to use a temporary anonymous hash value:

```
my $scalar_ref = \{_=>undef}->{_};
$$scalar_ref = "Hello!\n";
print $$scalar_ref;
```